# Increased speed despite false sharing

Tags: c++, multithreading, openmp, false-sharing

I've been doing some tests on OpenMP and made this program that should not scale because of false sharing of the array "sum". The problem I have is that it does scale. Even "worse":

- with 1 thread: 4 seconds (icpc), 4 seconds (g++)
- with 2 threads: 2 seconds (icpc), 2 seconds (g++)
- with 4 thread: 0.5 seconds (icpc), 1 seconds (g++)

I really don't get the speedup I get from 2 threads to 4 threads with the Intel compilers. But the most important is: why is scaling so good even though it should exhibit false sharing?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <chrono>

#include <array>

#include <omp.h>

int main(int argc, const char *argv[])
{
    const auto nb_threads = std::size_t{4};
    omp_set_num_threads(nb_threads);

    const auto num_steps = std::size_t{1000000000};
    const auto step = double{1.0 / num_steps};
    auto sum = std::array<double, nb_threads>{0.0};
    std::size_t actual_nb_threads;

    auto start_time = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    #pragma omp parallel
    {
        const auto id = std::size_t{omp_get_thread_num()};
        if (id == 0) {
            // This is needed because OMP might give us less threads
            // than the numbers of threads requested
            actual_nb_threads = omp_get_num_threads();
        }
        for (auto i = std::size_t{0}; i < num_steps; i += nb_threads) {
            auto x = double{(i + 0.5) * step};
            sum[id] += 4.0 / (1.0 + x * x);
        }
    }
    auto pi = double{0.0};
    for (auto id = std::size_t{0}; id < actual_nb_threads; id++) {
        pi += step * sum[id];
    }
    auto end_time = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    auto time = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::nanoseconds>(end_time - start_time).count();

    std::cout << "Pi: " << pi << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Time: " << time / 1.0e9 << " seconds" << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Total nb of threads actually used: " << actual_nb_threads << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: How fast is it when you fix the false sharing?

Comment: Exactly the same speed.

Comment: I don't think you have false sharing here in the first place. Each thread accesses only one dedicated element of the array. It's as if each thread had its own single variable to store the sum. You don't iterate over any array data in the concurrent code, so there's nothing to share in a false way.

Comment: Hanno: You should have false sharing here as the elements of sum should be in the same cache line which is 64 B on my computer.

Comment: Ok, I see what you mean. I though it was about accessing data from different cache lines. In this case, @Sneftel's answer is to the point.

Comment: Incidentally, you probably know this already, but it is a travesty not to be SIMD'ing that code.

Comment: What processor do you have?

Comment: Sneffel: I know. I am not looking for an optimized version here. I just want to understand what's going on.

Comment: MikeMB: A core i7 with 4 cores (and hyperthreading which makes 8 hardware threads).

Comment: Add a memory fence after `sum[id] += 4.0 / (1.0 + x * x);` to fully experience your false sharing. A simple `#pragma omp flush` would do it.

Answer (score 7):

That code definitely *could* exhibit false sharing, if the compiler chose to implement it that way. But that would be a silly thing for the compiler to do.

In the first loop, each thread only accesses one element of `sum`. There's no reason to make `num_steps` writes to the actual stack memory storing that element; it's much faster to just keep the value in a register, and write it back after the for-loop is over. Since the array is not volatile or atomic, there's nothing stopping the compiler from behaving in this way.

And, of course, in the second loop there's no writing to the array, so no false sharing.

Comment: Makes sense. The Intel video on OpenMP choose this example to explain false sharing and ask students to run it on their computer. so I expected their compilers not to "workaround" the problem. I still don't understand the speedup from 2 to 4 threads!

Comment: @InsideLoop It is a little weird. OpenMP optimizations are so opaque, though, that I'm hardly surprised. Some obscure little tuning heuristic deep in ICC happened to work better for 4 threads than 2 or 1.